# Look for a certain String inside another and count how many times it appears

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to search for a String inside a file content which I got into a String.

I've tried to use `Pattern` and `Matcher`, which worked for this case:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(</machine>)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()) //if the text "(</machine>)" was found, enter
{
    Counter++;
}

return Counter;
```

Then, I tried to use the same code to find how many tags I have:

```
Pattern tagsP = Pattern.compile("(</");
Matcher tagsM = tagsP.matcher(text);
while(tagsM.find()) //if the text "(</" was found, enter
{
    CounterTags++;
}

return CounterTags;
```

which in this case, the return value was always 0.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Did it give you false positive, where `</machine>` without `()` are matched?

Comment: The file which I am working with is a xml file.
The code I uploaded is an older version of my code,
So when I tried to find the (</machine>) String, it's worked,
but when I tried to find only the '(</' String to see how many tags I have,
the result was always 0.

Comment: Do you want to find the literal string `(</machine>)`, or do you want to find only `</machine>`? If it's the former, the code in the answer by Ankit doesn't work.

Comment: Both will do.
In my xml file it will, but when a text in the file can be just `</machine>`
it won't,
So the "more" correct option is `(</machine>)`

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify your requirement. Do include the non-working case and example input.

Comment: @almogeinstein is my code not working for you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the below code , btw not using `Pattern`:-

```
String actualString = "hello hi how(</machine>) are you doing. Again hi (</machine>) friend (</machine>) hope you are (</machine>)doing good.";
//actualString which you get from file content
String toMatch = Pattern.quote("(</machine>)");// for coverting to regex literal
int count = actualString .split(toMatch, -1).length - 1; // split the actualString to array based on toMatch , so final match count should be -1 than array length.
System.out.println(count);
```

**Output** :- `4`

Comment: Your code pass the `toMatch` to `split()` function, which expects a regex. This will cause problem if the input string contain meta-characters in regex syntax. Another thing is that `split()` by default will remove empty strings at the end of the array, which gives incorrect result for strings like `ppppp` or `aapp` when split by `p`. You need to call `split(regex, -1)` to preserve the empty strings at the end.

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks for mentioning, added that. Its always good to learn from people like you :)

Comment: You might want to escape regex meta-characters in `toMatch` with `Pattern.quote`, given that the OP has clarified the requirement.

Comment: When I use the `Pattern.quote` , there's a run-time error

Comment: Is your pattern to search is same as `(</machine>)` @almogeinstein

Comment: String toMatch = Pattern.quote("(</machine>)");



 int count = text.split(toMatch, -1).length - 1;

Comment: @almogeinstein its working for me, i just tested. whats your `text` here. i tested with `text = hello hi how(</machine>) are you doing. Again hi (</machine>) friend (</machine>) hope you are (</machine>)</machine></machine>doing good.</machine></machine>`

Comment: @AnkitNigam My `text` is a long file so I can't attach it or to copy his content over here, but i'm 100% sure it has (</machine>) inside the file

Comment: @almogeinstein for `(</machine>)` its working for me .. fine.. could you please check the error once again that why is it coming?

Comment: @almogeinstein all's well when end's well :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Apache `commons-lang` util library, there is a function [countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) exactly for you:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(text, "substring");
```

Also this function is null-safe.
I recommend you to explore [Apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/) libraries, they provide a lot of useful common util methods.

Comment: Can you give me the import line?

Comment: import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils; You need to download a JAR library from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi and include it to the build path of your project. Here is a tutorial: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29